# Why is the birthday problem not so surprising?

Tags: probability, intuition, birthday

I'm reading Blitzstein/Hwang's "Introduction to Probability". Here, they give an explanation as to why the conclusion obtained in the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) is not so surprising:

> [image]

I don't quite understand how this number of people makes it not so surprising. Could you expand a little bit?

Comment: There are 253 pairs and only 365 days.  Think about the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: If each pair of people has a $1/365$ chance of being a match, and there are 253 pairs, then maybe it doesn't seem so unlikely to have at least one match. If you were to perform 253 tosses of a biased coin with $P(\text{heads}) = 1/365$, you would not be surprised to get at least one heads. Perhaps the birthday situation is not so different, even though in the birthday problem the trials are not independent.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I thought about that but I feel it's a bit confusing: There are 253 pairs, but there are only 23 birthdays. This makes me think that the fact that there are 253 pairs is not so relevant.

Comment: the text of the book is seriously misleading as the $253$ pairs are all related, they aren't independent events

Comment: @Masacroso  While it's true that the $253$ events are not independent, they are in a limited sense "nearly so". If you know that one birthday match exists, this has a relatively small effect on the probability that additional matches exist, since the probability of a match is not vastly different for $22$ and for $23$ people. While it may not aid everyone's intuition, the proof that littleO's "coin toss" model is fairly accurate is in the pudding: $(364/365)^{23} = 0.4995\ldots$.

Comment: (Oops, the $23$ exponent in my comment should be $253$. Too late to fix!)

Comment: I am trying to show that this "coin toss model" corresponds to the leading order Stirling approximation of $\frac{365!}{(365-k)! 365^k}$ but I keep ending up with $e^{-k^2/365}$ instead of $e^{-k^2/730}$. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. I discarded the quadratic term in the logarithm and you can't do that in this situation. If you do that correctly then you find that indeed the coin toss model $p_k \sim (364/365)^{{k \choose 2}}$ agrees with the result of applying leading order Stirling approximation to $p_k=\frac{365!}{(365-k)! 365^k}$ combined with some Taylor approximation.

Comment: Note $253$ is also the answer to the question "For a greater than 50% chance that one person in a roomful of $n$ people has the same birthday as you"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first,the ${k \choose 2}$ pairs of people that exist each separately have probability $(364/365)$ to have the same birthday. This part is just a fact.

The part that is approximate is estimating the probability of matches being independent. This is obviously not exactly true, because if $\{ A,B \}$ is a match and $\{ B,C \}$ is a match then $\{ A,C \}$ is also a match. More dramatically, this estimate doesn't provide you with the fact that a match is exactly guaranteed with $k>365$. Still, it is fairly close to being correct when $k$ is small enough. One intuitive explanation is that when $k$ is small enough, there is an overwhelming probability that there are either $0$ or $1$ matches, and this scenario is well-handled by both models.

That said, if you doubt this approximate independence, the only thing that can definitely persuade you is to actually get into the weeds with it a bit. One way to proceed is to extract the $(364/365)^{k \choose 2}$ formula as an asymptotic estimate of $\frac{365!}{(365-k)! 365^k}$. This can be done as follows. First use Stirling's formula:

$$\frac{365!}{(365-k)! 365^k} \sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi} (365)^{365+1/2} e^{-365}}{\sqrt{2\pi} (365-k)^{365-k+1/2} e^{-(365-k)} 365^k}.$$

This step works better when $k$ is small, but works decently even when $k$ is close to $365$ (the relative error is never more than 10% even when $k=364$).

Now you simplify:

$$\frac{365!}{(365-k)! 365^k} \sim \frac{e^{-k}}{(1-k/365)^{365-k+1/2}}.$$

The next step is to approximate that denominator. It is exactly given by

$$e^{(365-k+1/2) \ln(1-k/365)}.$$

Now for small $k$ we can Taylor expand the logarithm. A trick you can use to save some effort in this is

$$\ln(1-k/365)=-\ln \left ( \frac{1}{1-k/365} \right ) = -\ln \left ( 1 + \frac{k/365}{1-k/365} \right ).$$

Expanding that to second order we have

$$(365-k+1/2) \ln(1-k/365) \sim -(365-k+1/2) \left ( \frac{k/365}{1-k/365} - \frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{k/365}{1-k/365} \right )^2 \right ).$$

So now the quantity we are interested in is

$$-k + (365-k+1/2) \left ( \frac{k/365}{1-k/365} - \frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{k/365}{1-k/365} \right )^2 \right ) \\
= \frac{(365-k+1/2)(k/365) - k + k^2/365}{1-k/365} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{(365-k+1/2) k^2/365^2}{(1-k/365)^2} \\
= \frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{k/365}{1-k/365} - \frac{k^2/365 - k^3/365^2 + (1/2) k^2/365^2}{(1-k/365)^2}\right ).$$

Expanding the denominators and then discarding all terms involving division by $365^2$ or higher powers yields an exponent of

$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{k-k^2}{365}$$

so our estimate for the match probability becomes

$$e^{-\frac{k \choose 2}{365}}.$$

Note that this last estimate is extremely bad if $k$ gets too close to $365$.

Compare this with

$$(364/365)^{k \choose 2}=e^{{k \choose 2} \ln(1-1/365)} \sim e^{-{k \choose 2}/365}$$

which is of course the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

So we have 253 pairs of people, each of them have a probability 1/365 to be a match.
Let N the number of pairs of people whose anniversary is the same day.
As mentioned in other answers, the probability to get a match is not so straightforward to estimate because the pairs are no independent.
However, the *expected* number of pairs is easy to compute:
E(N) = 253 / 365 ~= 0.69

This expectation may be re-written as follow:
E(N) = P(N>=1) +  P(N>=2) + P(N=>3) + ...

And now here is the intuition: if you expect that 1 pair is unlikely, observing 2 or more pairs should be still *much more* unlikely... and the value of P(N>=2) + P(N=>3) + ... should be small compared to P(N=1). This tell us that  P(N>=1) cannot be so small, ie at least a collision cannot be unlikely.